# Unable to retrieve Firestore Documents using Collection

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Are you please able to look at the following and help me understand why my documents fail to retrieve from Firestore? My code is below:

```
class ContactStore : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var datas = [contactDataType]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData() {
        
      db.collection("Contact Details").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
          print("No documents")
          return
        }
          
        self.datas = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> contactDataType? in
          return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: contactDataType.self)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

My struct is as follows

```
struct contactDataType : Identifiable, Codable {
    
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var adno : String
    var fullname : String
    var firstname : String
    var lastname : String
    var registrationgroup : String
    var priority1relation : String
    var priority1fullname : String
    var priority1maintelephone : String
    var priority1mobile : String
    var priority2relation : String
    var priority2fullname : String
    var priority2maintelephone : String
    var priority2mobile : String
    var priority3relation : String
    var priority3fullname : String
    var priority3maintelephone : String
    var priority3mobile : String
    var priority4relation : String
    var priority4fullname : String
    var priority4maintelephone : String
    var priority4mobile : String
```

I am able to retrieve the documents using the following code,

```
class ContactStore : ObservableObject{

    @Published var datas = [contactDataType]()
    @AppStorage("selectedSchool") var selectedSchool: String = "selectedSchool"


    init() {

        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("School Name/\(selectedSchool/School Assets/\(**Struggling with this bit**)/Contact Details").getDocuments { (snap, err) in

            if err != nil{

                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }

            for i in snap!.documents{

                let id = i.documentID
                let adno = i.get("ID") as? String ?? ""
                let fullname = i.get("Full Name") as? String ?? ""
                let firstname = i.get("First Name") as? String ?? ""
                let lastname = i.get("Last Name") as? String ?? ""
                let registrationgroup = i.get("Registration Group") as? String ?? ""
                let priority1relation = i.get("Priority 1 Relation") as? String ?? ""
                let priority1fullname = i.get("Priority 1 Full Name") as? String ?? ""
                let priority1maintelephone = i.get("Priority 1 Main Telephone") as? String ?? ""
                let priority1mobile = i.get("Priority 1 Mobile") as? String ?? ""
                let priority2relation = i.get("Priority 2 Relation") as? String ?? ""
                let priority2fullname = i.get("Priority 2 Full Name") as? String ?? ""
                let priority2maintelephone = i.get("Priority 2 Main Telephone") as? String ?? ""
                let priority2mobile = i.get("Priority 2 Mobile") as? String ?? ""
                let priority3relation = i.get("Priority 3 Relation") as? String ?? ""
                let priority3fullname = i.get("Priority 3 Full Name") as? String ?? ""
                let priority3maintelephone = i.get("Priority 3 Main Telephone") as? String ?? ""
                let priority3mobile = i.get("Priority 3 Mobile") as? String ?? ""
                let priority4relation = i.get("Priority 4 Relation") as? String ?? ""
                let priority4fullname = i.get("Priority 4 Full Name") as? String ?? ""
                let priority4maintelephone = i.get("Priority 4 Main Telephone") as? String ?? ""
                let priority4mobile = i.get("Priority 4 Mobile") as? String ?? ""


                self.datas.append(contactDataType(id: id, adno: adno, fullname: fullname, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, registrationgroup: registrationgroup, priority1relation: priority1relation, priority1fullname: priority1fullname, priority1maintelephone: priority1maintelephone, priority1mobile: priority1mobile, priority2relation: priority2relation, priority2fullname: priority2fullname, priority2maintelephone: priority2maintelephone, priority2mobile: priority2mobile, priority3relation: priority3relation, priority3fullname: priority3fullname, priority3maintelephone: priority3maintelephone, priority3mobile: priority3mobile, priority4relation: priority4relation, priority4fullname: priority4fullname, priority4maintelephone: priority4maintelephone, priority4mobile: priority4mobile))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Firebase Structure]

**So overall, I'm struggling to either pass the document ID into the path in the second code or retreive my documents using the first. I know it would be better using the first, but I would really like to pass the document ID's into the document path rather than create collection group queries as it doesn't seem to match with would I would like to do.

I understand the naming structure isn't quite right and should avoid spaces**

At this moment in time I have set my rules to read for all so I know this is not a security issue.

Questions -

1. Am I able to pass the Document ID into a path? I'm not sure and I can't find any documentation on this although I have managed this through AppStorage for Selected School
2. Is Collection Group Queries the better way to go for this?

Thank you for any and all advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't build the full path to the subcollection to query, including all of the nested document IDs, then you won't be able to query it directly.  A full path is required - there are no wildcards.

If know the name of the subcollection, you can do a collection group query, and that will query all subcollections with that exact same name.  If you don't want all of the documents among all of those subcollections, you can filter the query to find what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, thanks for the response. 

So, there is no way to retrieve all document ID's and query against the school name for example to complete the path?

The problem I have with Collection Group queries is that I do know the sub collection name but then I'm going to struggle using the set the fields it requires to set one up unless I'm looking at this wrong? Thanks for your response.

Comment: You can certainly make a query for all documents, get their IDs, then make more queries for each subcollection that might be present under each one.  It's not possible to do that all at once.